# Subscribing to Observable or Driver takes too long in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex, rx-cocoa

I noticed that RxSwift slows down the app, I don't know if this is my fault or the framework.

I have binding inside custom class of UICollectionViewCell, which is fired for configuring cell. For example this part of code:

```
viewModel.observableIsHighlighted.asDriver().drive(onNext: { isHighlighted in
    // do nothing
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
viewModel.observableIsMarked.asDriver().drive(onNext: { isMarked in
    // do nothing
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

where `observableIsHighlighted`, `observableIsMarked` are just `BehaviorRelay<Bool>`, takes around 16-20 milliseconds which is unacceptable for UICollectionView of course.

Another part like this:

```
imageViewTapGestureRecognizer.rx.event.bind(onNext: { _ in
    // do nothing
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

takes around 12 milliseconds.

**Question**

Is it something wrong in my approach or binding in RxSwift is not accurate for views like `UICollectionView`?

Of course, I assume that binding in RxSwift is exactly for things like `UICollectionView`.

**Edit**

How am I measuring time?

I use `CACurrentMediaTime()` multiplied by `1000`. I know it's the best way, but methods that are quite simple always take 0 ms, so it suggest that 10-20 ms methods, are should be improved.

Comment: I'd love to know the way you measured the delay!

Comment: I'm using CACurrentMediaTime(), I know it's not the best way, but I just place code inside instantiating one CACurrentMediaTime() and second CACurrentMediaTime(), then just subtract each other. I guess it's not that bad, because the subtraction between normal parts of code is just 0. Additionally I'm checking that because my UICollectionView stutters.

Comment: I've just measured using CACurrentMediaTime  and the delay is 0.06 milliseconds on main. and 3 milliseconds when posted on background and listened on main.

Comment: You mean that you measured this parts of code and the delay is just 0.06 milliseconds? I don't know what to think about it...

Comment: I’ll post some code tomorrow

Comment: I think I found solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe, but I updated `RxSwift` and `RxCocoa` to `4.1.0` from `4.0` inside my `Podfile` and now it works perfectly.

Methods from the question take around 0-1 ms now.

Hope this question will help others or maybe anyone would know why I experienced this behavior.

Comment: Very interesting! It is a good approach to upgrade/downgrade the pod version and compare the behavior.